# how to implement vcard on website, to open up email program and add as contact

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm trying to add a button to my site, with the purpose of opening up a vcf file. I want it to work just like the "mailto:"

```
<a href="mailto:random.mail@gmail.com">
```

since this opens up the email app.
Is there a way to implement the same functionality with a vcf file?

```
<a href="../resources/vcardfile.vcf" download>
    <button class="save-button" t="[html]contact.saveContact"></button>
</a>
```

Maybe something in this direction.

Comment: You are not in control over which application _my_ system might use as default for certain file types. The most you can do is offer this VCF for download - what happens afterwards, is out of your hands.

Comment: You're looking for a *CardDAV API*...